# How to handle Hibernate Sessions when using EntityManagers?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

Out team is currently programming a JavaEE webapplication for use on a Tomcat appserver.

We want to handle persistence using Hibernate (5.0.1). To access the database entities, we use `EntityManagers` (not from JPA, they were implemented by us, see below) which provide methods to list, create and delete rows in the associated tables. The model classes use Hibernate Annotations for the mapping.

We also have a static class `PersistenceController` which initializes Hibernate's `SessionFactory` and provides a static method to get a newly opened session.

Of course we want to be able to use unit tests to test the functionality of our classes, so the `PersistenceController` is a little thorn in our eyes.

Someone else recommended me to move everything from the `PersistenceController` into the `EntityManager` base class. He wasn't sure if this would have any side consequences though.

So I thought "let's ask the hive mind". What would be the best practice in this case?

(If more code is needed, I'm happy to provide it)

**PersistenceController**

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class PersistenceController {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .configure() // configures settings from hibernate.cfg.xml
                .build();
        try {
            sessionFactory = new MetadataSources(registry).buildMetadata()
                    .buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // The registry would be destroyed by the SessionFactory, but we had
            // trouble building the SessionFactory
            // so destroy it manually.
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public static Session openSession() {
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }
}
```

**EntityManager**

```
import java.util.List;

public abstract class EntityManager<T extends PersistenceEntity> {

    public abstract List<T> listAll();

    public abstract void save(T entity);

    public abstract void delete(T entity);

}
```

**ProductManager**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import etepat.model.product.Product;

public class ProductManager extends EntityManager<Product> {

    public ProductManager() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Product> listAll() {
        try (Session session = PersistenceController.openSession()) {
            Transaction transaction = null;
            try {
                transaction = session.beginTransaction();
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                List<Product> returned = session.createCriteria(Product.class)
                        .list();
                transaction.commit();
                return returned;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (transaction != null) {
                    transaction.rollback();
                }
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return new ArrayList<Product>();
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Product entity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Product entity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: Are your `EntityManagers` somehow related to JPA [EntityManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html)? Naming clash like that can't be good for future discussions, and what you wrote looks like DAO pattern.

Comment: Not that I know. `EntityManager` is an abstract class which forces subclasses to implement the functions `T list()`, `void create(T entity)` and `delete(T entity)`, where T must be a subtype of the abstract class `PersistenceEntity`. It is in no way related to the class you linked to.

Comment: Well then, I strongly suggest changing that - using the name of the (arguably) most important class defined by JPA (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqw.html)) in a related context for your own purposes is a really bad idea just waiting to confuse every programmer that will ever have to look at that code.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of your `EntityManager`(better call `BaseDao` or `GenericDao`) is good but needs some improvements.

First, base CRUD methods don't have to be abstract. They can simply persist/load/delete/list on generic type `T`. That way you don't have to write these methods on each subclass. See this generic dao approach https://github.com/athanasiosem/Hibernate-Generic-Dao-Java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/demien/hibgeneric/dao/GenericDAOImpl.java

Second is, you're managing transactions manually, is there a good reason to do so?
With container managed transactions(using annotations) you don't need to, and they greatly simplify your code by eliminating the boilerplate try{...}catch{//rollback}.

Basically, with a `GenericDao<T>` and container managed transactions you don't need this code at all, your classes sublass the `GenericDao<ConcreteType>` with concrete types and they're ready to do CRUD on database without a single line of code.

Comment: Note, that he does mention the use of Tomcat - not a JavaEE container.

Comment: You're right, just saw, and Tomcat is just a servlet container. But the advice stands still, I suggest him to use declarative transactions provided by Spring in that case.

Comment: Currently looking at Spring (I knew it existed, but never used it actively).
I also took a look at the GenericDao you linked to, interestingly it uses basically the same code we use in the PersistenceController. The project is also under MIT license and sadly doesn't offer a pom.xml. I'm not that familiar with licenses yet. If I get it right I could copy the source files into our project and put the copyright notice above, right?

Comment: Yes. In any case I suggest you look at spring-data project, it provides these things out of the box. http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/